# Are aphrosidacs in perfume permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, perfume

There are some perfumes that use pheromones and musk, with the intention of making members of the opposite sex chemically attracted to the perfume user. Are these permissible? I think it goes under the ruling of going closer to zina.

What if those chemicals don't really work? Let's say a person really likes a perfume that happens to have something like [Androstadienone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androstadienone), but isn't wearing it for the purpose of sexual attraction and doesn't find any response from the chemicals. But the perfume itself is still sold under the marketing tagline of making people sexually attracted to them.

Comment: An absurd number of things are sold under the marketing tagline of sexual attraction these days.

Comment: As technology advances, there will be as many questions in the form of "is it halal/haram" as you want. I'm not against answering them one by one, but I think it is also good to understand the principles of Islam and examine the situation for oneself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the popular hadeeth, the first one in Saheeh al-Bukhaari:

> Actions are judged/rewarded by their intentions...

Now let's look at some examples:

1. A man goes for jihad. But his intention is to travel for marrying a woman (from the hadeeth)
2. A youth visits an Islamic lecture but it's because many young girls come there.
3. A man is forced to say other than the shahaadah but he does not mean it (Bilaal R.A. was force but he was stronger).
4. A man pays a bribe (he only does it to get his passport on time for hajj and not doing so he won't get his passport).
5. Your kid needs a cough syrup (but some people use it to get high/drunk).

So you see, everything comes down to your intentions.

Now we see from the various ahadeeth that the Prophet (S) used to like the MUSK perfume. Musk is taken from the Gazelle but due to its cost, it is made today using chemicals.

So if you like musk because it was liked by the prophet (s) you are not committing a sin. But if you do it because you think girls are going to like it, you know the answer by now :)

Then comes the final part of my answer... Some things are made for a specific bad purpose. If for example, you walk on the street, I think you'll instantly know by the smell, if someone is using the so-called perfume. And if you get that smell, what will be your thoughts?

So if something has an intended purpose and that purpose is not good, I think you should avoid it. But if for example, you wear musk and someone is drawn by that smell, it's not your problem. But you must be honest about it. Your niyyah must be pure.